# IPSEC vpn problem

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vpnc

I am trying to connect into a vpn "cisco asa" but it is not work, checked the logs .. I asked a friend to test the connection with his laptop and worked, he was able to connect... I also tried to use Shrew vpn and didn't work as well.Any ideas please ?

```
Jun 17 21:41:16 raikone-X555UB gnome-session[2599]:     QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
Jun 17 21:41:19 raikone-X555UB gnome-session[2599]: (gala:3401): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Jun 17 21:41:19 raikone-X555UB gnome-session[2599]: (gala:3401): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Jun 17 21:41:42 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268102.2688] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0" name="VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede" pid=3461 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun 17 21:41:42 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268102.2837] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 13880
Jun 17 21:41:42 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268102.3019] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Jun 17 21:41:42 raikone-X555UB gnome-session[2599]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268109.6510] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede (fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede")
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: ** Message: vpnc started with pid 13895
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268109.6841] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268109.6845] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: Error binding to source port. Try '--local-port 0'
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:500: Address already in use
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: ** (nm-vpnc-service:13880): WARNING **: vpnc exited with error code 1
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: (nm-vpnc-service:13880): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_source_remove: assertion 'tag > 0' failed
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <warn>  [1529268109.6873] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <warn>  [1529268109.6876] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268109.6878] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268109.6878] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Jun 17 21:41:49 raikone-X555UB NetworkManager[1377]: <info>  [1529268109.6887] vpn-connection[0x184a5e0,fb6db216-0efa-4bc6-80ad-9f525cedfcf0,"VPN BAI Novo Edificio Sede
```

Comment: ohh,, two days ago this vpn was working...